# using gifs with space invaders

Tags: gif, jcreator

I have borrowed code online for a clone of the space invaders game. I have found the gifs I would like to use on the same website as the code. I tried to contact the person who wrote this code for questions about where to save the gifs to, as to use them but i have recieved no reply. I am wondering where i should save the gifs to so that they will show up in the clone.

URL for links to original code and gifs. https://github.com/jamillion/spaceinvaders

```
try
{
    ship = ImageIO.read(new File("ship.gif"));
}
```

Comment: thank you Alan for spacing it for me.

Answer (score 0):

The gif's should be placed in the same directory as the code. The code is trying to read the file with no path, so by default it will be the current working directory.

To make things easier, you could download the zip (or tar) from github, and place the entire contents into a directory, then run the java per the instructions.

https://github.com/jamillion/spaceinvaders/archive/master.zip

Comment: thank you. i know this will sound dumb and I'm waiting for downvotes but how exactly do i save it into the same directory? thank you so much

Comment: I updated my answer, but I think the easiest method is to download the zip from github, and unzip the contents into one folder.

And don't worry about sounding dumb, we're all here to learn.